# Contar itens separados por ponto e vírgula em campo de tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados mysql onde no campo **tags** são armazenados valores nesse formato:

```
+-----------------+
| tags            |
+-----------------+
| B27;C38;H45;B27 |
| C38;H45         |
| B24;C45;L55;K98 |
+-----------------+
```

Preciso contar, via mysql ou php, os itens únicos dessa coluna, linha por linha, de forma que o resultado me traga a contagem dos itens únicos:

```
B27 -> 2
C38 -> 2
H45 -> 2
B24 -> 1
C45 -> 1
L55 -> 1
K98 -> 1
```

Desde já eu agradeço.

Comment: Você gostaria de contar esses itens utilizando a linguagem sql mesmo?

Comment: @thiagodias Pode ser via mysql ou php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função `explode(";", $tags)` para remover o `';'` para separar as tags, e `array_count_values()` para contar quantos itens iguais contém no array:

```
<?php
$tags = 'B27;C38;H45;B27;C38;H45;B24;C45;L55;K98';
$array = array(explode(";", $tags));
var_dump(array_count_values($array[0]));

foreach (array_count_values($array[0]) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." => ".$value."\n";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Seu código, assim como a do amigo Gabriel, irá me ajudar muito!

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, você vai pegar os dados e coloca-lo em um array sem repetir os itens.

Considerei que os dados vão estar todos em uma variável separados por `;`, caso não seja assim você pode junta-los tudo em uma variável e rodas o código abaixo.

Segue o código e php:

```
//Dados recebidos
$field = "B27;C38;H45;B27;C38;H45;B24;C45;L55;K98";

//Separa os dados em um array
$tags = explode(';', $field);

$countTags = array();

//Percorre o array e junta itens repitidos mostrando sua quantidade
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if(array_key_exists($tag, $countTags)){
        $countTags[$tag] += 1;
    }else{
        $countTags[$tag] = 1;
    }
}

//Mostra o array
var_dump($countTags);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Seu código, assim como a do amigo Luís Eduardo, me ajudou muito!